# Depth Map bad result

Tags: python, opencv

I use OpenCV with Python for tests with depth mapping. I found [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html) tutorial and I use the fragment of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fEhUO9JP-I) video for tests.

This is my code for single frame:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test1.mp4')

ret, frame = cap.read()


plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))
plt.show()
left = cv2.cvtColor(frame[0:720, 0:640], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
right = cv2.cvtColor(frame[0:720, 640:1280], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

stereo = cv2.StereoBM_create(numDisparities=16, blockSize=15)
disparity = stereo.compute(left,right)


norm_image = cv2.normalize(disparity, None, alpha = 0, beta = 1,           norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)

plt.grid(False)
plt.imshow(norm_image)
plt.show()
cap.release()
```

And the [results](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1prb5qCfQ_aUsJ74-KQ9d6LGf-B9KjeNO) is very bad. What do I do wrong?